# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, typeerror

I read everything I found, I even got to the second page of google.
I deleted `node_module`s and after `npm install`.
I keep having this:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
_callee$
C:/src/client/proxy.ts:28
  25 |   });
  26 | }
  27 | 
> 28 | export async function call<RESULT>(method: string, ...params: any[]) {
  29 |   return rpc.call<RESULT>(method, ...params);
  30 | }
  31 |
```

The piece of code you see is part of an SDK that I am using.
The exact same functions are used in a tutorial I downloaded. If I run the tutorial it works,
while if I run my React.js web-app I get the error.

I have compared the `package.json` files and they have the same dependencies.

I don't have much experience so I don't know if it's useful: the `tsconifg.json` files are different.

This is **proxy.ts**:

```
import { WindowPostMessageProxy } from '@ont-community/window-post-message-proxy';
import { Rpc } from '../rpc/rpc';

let windowProxy: WindowPostMessageProxy;
let rpc: Rpc;

export function registerClient({
  logMessages = false,
  logWarnings = false
}: {
  logMessages?: boolean;
  logWarnings?: boolean;
}) {
  windowProxy = new WindowPostMessageProxy({
    name: 'page',
    target: 'content-script',
    logMessages,
    suppressWarnings: !logWarnings
  });
  rpc = new Rpc({
    source: 'page',
    destination: 'background',
    logMessages: false,
    postMessage: windowProxy.postMessage.bind(windowProxy, window)
  });
}

export async function call<RESULT>(method: string, ...params: any[]) {
  return rpc.call<RESULT>(method, ...params);
}
```

**rpc.ts**:

```
import { Caller, Tunnel, TunnelOptions } from './tunnel';

export type MethodType = (...params: any[]) => any;

interface MethodCallType {
  method: string;
  params: any[];
}

export class Rpc {
  private tunnel: Tunnel<MethodCallType>;
  private methods: Map<string, MethodType>;

  constructor(options: TunnelOptions) {
    options.messageHandler = this.messageHandler.bind(this);

    this.tunnel = new Tunnel(options);
    this.methods = new Map();
  }

  call<RESULT = any>(method: string, ...params: any[]) {
    const msg = {
      method,
      params
    };

    return this.tunnel.send<RESULT>(msg);
  }

  register(name: string, method: MethodType) {
    this.methods.set(name, method);
  }

  private messageHandler(msg: MethodCallType, caller: Caller) {
    const method = this.methods.get(msg.method);

    if (method === undefined) {
      throw new Error('Unregistered method call: ' + msg.method);
    }

    return method.call(caller, ...msg.params);
  }
}
```

Comment: rpc is undefined... where is rpc instanciated?

Comment: could you log the entire file of proxy.ts ?

Comment: I edited with whole proxy.ts  file

Comment: @DarioRega done!

Comment: the rpc is from a node module or custom ? if custom please show the code too

Comment: It's custom, i did it